# listen call backlog in c

Tags: c, linux, tcp

i gone through with the lots material of networking in c and also searched a lot on internet, but still there is doubt in mind that what is purpose of backlog in listen ().

Note :- i also gone through the with same question/answer in stackoverflow, but still m confused.

can any one explain me in simple language?

And if backlog queue in listen is number of pending or incomplete request than if i provided 5 in backlog parameter, still more than 5 connection can also connect.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you `listen` on a port, under the covers TCP will complete your connections (i.e. the 3 way handshake) and put them in a queue up to the size of the backlog queue.  When you `accept` a connection your pgm begins to process it and that slot opens in the queue for another (potential) connection.  So if you are currently processing (have accepted) 5 connections and you have a backlog size of 5 then another 5 connections can still be made by the tcp layer.

Comment: so if i will give wait(60) above the accept call and than continiously requesting for 6 connection in that 60 second. does listen will give error ??

Comment: I'm sorry.  You lost me.  I'm not sure what you are asking.  When connections arrive depend on when clients connect.  When you call `accept` you will either (1) be returned a new socket connection if one is available in queue; (2) block if there is no connection available (or return immediately with EAGAIN if the listening socket is non-blocking).  If you are slow in accepting connections and your queue fills up then tcp will start rejecting any new connection requests.